# namespace boost has no member

Tags: c++, boost

I downloaded the latest version of Boost libraries 1_60_0 and I tried to use it but I quickly ran into troubles.

```
boost::unordered_map<int, int> map;
```

This piece of code says "namespace boost has no member unordered_map". I checkd the file, it is there though. The same happened for basically everything I tried to acces from the boost namespace.

Header includes are as follows:

```
#include <D:/IP/boost_1_60_0/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <D:/IP/boost_1_60_0/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <D:/IP/boost_1_60_0/boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>
#include <D:/IP/boost_1_60_0/boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <D:/IP/boost_1_60_0/boost/graph/floyd_warshall_shortest.hpp>
#include <D:/IP/boost_1_60_0/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <D:/IP/boost_1_60_0/boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
```

I'm guessing I should include something more, but no clue what. Any tips?

Comment: Are there any other errors in your build log? I'm guessing the included file isn't opened or read

Comment: Why do you guys never follow [Da Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)? ))

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/5lu216r1d/) it starts like this

Comment: Add the compiler argument `-ID:/IP/boost_1_60_0/` and include your header like `#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unordered_map.hpp` includes other boost header files this way:

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
```

Which means that the `boost` folder has to be set as an additional include directory for this to work.

I'm assuming you're compiling on MSVC, if so, right click your project : properties -> C/C++ -> General and add the folder `D:/IP/boost_1_60_0/` as Additional Include Directory.

The [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide) also answers this question for you.

Comment: Like described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide)

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thanks. But now I have a different problem. I was also using OpenCV, can one include more than one directory? Cause now the CV files are not found.

Comment: @LorenaSfăt you can add so many directories as you need. But also consider that some libraries are not header only.

Comment: @LorenaSfat (sorry) Yes you can quite easily, just separate them with a ;